# gcc compile error with sine and boost:interval

Tags: c++, boost

I'm required to run some code on a linux (CentOs 6.7) server with gcc/g++ installed (7.2.0) and boost (1.66) (**Edit:** not only 1.66, an older version of boost interfered. Keep your machines clean guys). I specified my interval type with policies like so:

```
// test.cpp
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>   

namespace bn = boost::numeric;
namespace bi = bn::interval_lib;

using Interval = bn::interval<
      double,
      bi::policies<
          bi::save_state<bi::rounded_transc_std<double> >,
          bi::checking_base<double>
      >
  >;
```

Now I want to do some simple calculation like:

```
// still test.cpp
int main() 
{
    Interval iv_arg {1.0};
    Interval res = sin(iv_arg);
}
```

On my local machine, a mac, compiling with clang works perfectly fine. However, as soon as I try to run it on the server, compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` I'm getting the error:

> /usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:59: error:
>   'to_int' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were
>   found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation
>   [-fpermissive]    T int_down(const T& x) { this->downward(); return
>   to_int(x); }
>                                                        ~~~~~~^~~ /usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:59: note:
>   declarations in dependent base
>   'boost::numeric::interval_lib::detail::c99_rounding' are not found by
>   unqualified lookup
>   /usr/include/boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:71:59: note: use
>   'this->to_int' instead

There is some more info which seems irrelevant to the topic, but I can include it if it might help. I tried to google a little but couldn't find anything relevant. If possible, I would like to find a solution that doesn't require any changes on the server. Does anyone have an idea or encountered a similar problem before?

Comment: Show the *exact* compilation command, and provide some [MCVE]

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch added the compilation command. What is not minimal, complete or verifiable about my example?

Comment: No, you did give an [MCVE] (if the two code chunks go together)

Comment: BTW, are you sure you have only one version of boost? Did you check with `-H` (passed to `g++` and to `clang++`) that the *same* `boost/numeric/interval.hpp` get included in both cases? What version of Boost?

Comment: Please specify the version of boost in the post. *latest version* is likely to be wrong not too soon.

Comment: @Walter it is already wrong.

Comment: @sehe that's what I reckoned and that's why I'm asking him to provide that detail.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that seems to indeed be the problem, there might be several versions of boost. I just found version 1.41 there, and adding up with sehes answer, this won't compile. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First version of boost that compiles this is 1.58

- [boost 1.57](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E3MbaRSOzHPDWILi) ERROR
- [boost 1.58](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gyOZsUr2LRnqIolA) OK